# How to get value in different page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class, tags, element

What I need to get value price but different item in another page.

Item 1

```
<div class="price-box">
<p class="old-price">
    <span class="price-label">Old Price:</span>
    <span class="price" id="old-price-1696"> IDR 170,000 </span>
</p>
<p class="special-price"> 
    <span class="price-label">Special Price</span> 
    <span class="price" id="product-price-1696"> IDR 139,000 </span>
</p>
```

Item 2

```
<div class="price-box">
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-4">
    <span class="price">IDR  159,000</span>
</span>
```

I want to get value on item 1 is "IDR 139,000" and item 2 is "IDR 159,000" don't use id="product-price-4" because the id change every page.

Comment: try in hidden field ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), *return the elements that match the specified group of selectors*

Try this:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.price-box .special-price .price,.regular-price .price'),function(item) {
  alert(item.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div class="price-box">
  <p class="old-price">
    <span class="price-label">Old Price:</span>
    <span class="price" id="old-price-1696"> IDR 170,000 </span>
  </p>
  <p class="special-price">
    <span class="price-label">Special Price</span>
    <span class="price" id="product-price-1696"> IDR 139,000 </span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="price-box">
  <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-4">
    <span class="price">IDR  159,000</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: i implement with javascript. :)

Comment: how to define a function with a return value?